# How to get the data of each line from a file?

Tags: arrays, perl

Here, I want to print the data in each line as 3 separate values with "`:`" as separator. The file `BatmanFile.txt` has the following details:

```
Bruce:Batman:bat@bat.com
Santosh:Bhaskar:santosh@santosh.com
```

And the output I expected was:

```
Bruce
Batman
bat@bat.com
Santosh
Bhaskar
santosh@santosh.com
```

The output after executing the script was:

```
Bruce
Batman
bat@bat.com
Bruce
Batman
bat@bat.com
```

Please explain me what I am missing here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'BatmanFile.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my @resultarray;
while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    #print $line;    
    chomp $line;
    my @linearray = split(":", $line);
    push(@resultarray, @linearray);
    print join("\n",$resultarray[0]),"\n";
    print join("\n",$resultarray[1]),"\n";
    print join("\n",$resultarray[2]),"\n";
}
close $info;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
push(@resultarray, @linearray);
```

you're pushing `@linearray` into `@resultarray` at the end, so index `0` through `2` is still the items from the first time you pushed `@linearray`.

To overwrite `@resultarray` with the values from the second iteration, do:

```
@resultarray = @linearray;
```

instead.

Alternatively, use `unshift` to place `@linearray` at the start of `@resultarray`, [as suggested by Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853200/perl-scripting-how-to-get-the-data-in-each-line/39853299?noredirect=1#comment66994291_39853299):

```
unshift @resultarray, @linearray;
```

Comment: Or us `unshift` to put it on the beginning.

Comment: Thank you @Sobrique  and Mathias.

Answer (score 5):

You are looping through file line by line. You have stored all lines (after splitting) in an array. Once the loop finishes you have all data in `resultarray` array, just print whole array after the loop (instead of printing just first 3 indexes which are you doing at the moment).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @resultarray;
while( my $line = <DATA>){
    chomp $line;
    my @linearray = split(":", $line);
    push @resultarray, @linearray;
}
print "$_\n" foreach @resultarray;
__DATA__
Bruce:Batman:bat@bat.com
Santosh:Bhaskar:santosh@santosh.com
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/WRF2VE)

---

You can avoid all variables and do something like below

```
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    print "$_\n" foreach split(":");
}
```

---

One liner:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){chomp; push @result, split(":",$_);} print "$_\n" foreach @result' testdata.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Chankey.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW you can easily avoid all the array operations. See the edited answer (2nd section).

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation on this and giving me best ways to get the output. However, I needed those variables for some other task, so I'd accepted the other answer. And Thanks a lot for sharing these tips.

Comment: Oh if you need them then it doesn't apply :)

Answer (score 2):

So, you just want to [transliterate](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) `:` to `\n`?

```
$ perl -pe 'tr/:/\n/' data.txt
```

Output:

```
Bruce
Batman
bat@bat.com
Santosh
Bhaskar
santosh@santosh.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'BatmanFile.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my @resultarray;
while( my $line = <$info>)  {   

    #print $line;    
    chomp $line;
    my @linearray = split(":", $line);
    #push(@resultarray, @linearray);
    print join("\n",$linearray[0]),"\n";
    print join("\n",$linearray[1]),"\n";
    print join("\n",$linearray[2]),"\n";

}
close $info;
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Code-only answers are discouraged; some explanation would be helpful. (See [answer] for more information.) Regarding the code itself, joining a 1-item list isn't going to get you a very interesting result.